# What is angle property in rotation event in hammer.js

Tags: javascript, rotation, hammer.js

In hammer js what i wanted to do save the rotation of object, so where use left the rotation they can start from same.

But i found that its not working and in event there are two attributes one is `rotation` and another is `angle`.
may be i am missing something and i couldn't find documentation regarding angel property.

here is demo which is not able to save rotation after one cycle of rotate.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZYgKd/